# how to read char* using serialization

Tags: c++, qt

Writing char* into a file using serialization, it is writing values well. but the same file when trying to read the char* values it is giving junk values.

```
main ()
{
    char*   FullName =  "Ernestine Waller";
    char*   CompleteAddress =  "824 Larson Drv, Silver Spring, MD 20910";

    ofstream ofs("fifthgrade.ros", ios::binary);
    ofs.write((char *)&FullName, sizeof(char*) );
    cout << sizeof(FullName) << endl << sizeof(CompleteAddress) << endl ;
    ofs.write((char *)&CompleteAddress, sizeof(char*));

    ofs.close();

    char*   FullName1;
    char*   CompleteAddress1;

    ifstream ifs("fifthgrade.ros", ios::binary);
    ifs.read((char *)&FullName1, sizeof(char*));
    ifs.read((char *)&CompleteAddress1, sizeof(char*));

    cout << "Student Information\n";
    cout << FullName1 <<  endl <<CompleteAddress1 << endl;
    ifs.close();

    return 0;
}
```

reading and writing in the main is giving correct values.
but only reading

```
int main()
{
    char*   FullName;
    char*   CompleteAddress;

    ifstream ifs("fifthgrade.ros", ios::binary);

    ifs.read((char *)&FullName, 8/*sizeof(char*)*/);

    ifs.read((char *)&CompleteAddress, 8/*sizeof(char*)*/);

    cout << "Student Information\n";
    cout << FullName <<  endl <<CompleteAddress;

    return 0;
}
```

gives junk values. how to read the char* values ?

Comment: I don't believe you when you say it's outputting those strings well at all.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting junk values as there's a far bit of *undefined behaviour* in your code.

`sizeof(char*)` gives the size of the `char*` pointer, not the length of the string.

Use `strlen` to get the string length.

Also you need to allocate memory for your string buffers for receiving data input. As a starting point for example, use `char fullName1[32];` which gives you 31 characters plus NULL termination to play with. There are better approaches, but doing this will get you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read the strings into char* when you haven't reserved memory for them. Since you are using c++, why not use std::string instead of char arrays and read the strings into them. Memory management becomes then a non-issue.